# Collapsible order status table span problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to recreate this order status HTML/CSS: 
   https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/order-status-table-html-css-help/101907/3

And encountered the same problem with the author. The table is in collapsed form when not yet clicked then expands then an order number is chosen.

In case of having multiple account numbers, how can I open ONLY the CHOSEN ROW because in my case, it opens all the account number details, not the one chosen.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.closedArrow').click(function() {
    $('.expanded').toggle();
    $('.collapsed').toggle();
    $( "span.closedArrow" ).toggleClass( "openArrow" );
    
});
  });
```

```css
.closedArrow {
 <!-- background: url('http://is200.imagesocket.com/images/2014/10/29/2716484-3exx.png') no-repeat 1px 1px; --> 
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 4px; 
 cursor:pointer;
}

.openArrow {
 <!-- background: url('http://is200.imagesocket.com/images/2014/10/29/2716483-0cvp.png') no-repeat 1px 1px; -->
 padding-left: 20px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.steps {
    margin:0 0 20px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.green {
 background:#7dba00 !important; 
 color: #666666 !important;
}

.grey {
 color: #666666 !important;
}

.open .green:after  {
 border-left-color: #7dba00 !important;
}

.wrap .num.last:after {
 display:none
}
.wrap .num.last:before {
 display:none
}

.black {
 background:#000 !important; 
 color:#fff!important;
}

.open .black:after  {
 border-left-color: #000 !important; 
 color:#fff!important;
}

.steps li {
 float:left;
 position:relative;
}

.wrap {
 float:left;
}

.num {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#7dba00;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 4px 0 0;
}

.num b, .steps p span {
 position:relative;
 z-index:2; 
 display:block;
}

.num:after {
    content:" ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 14px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
    border-left: 14px solid #7dba00;
    position:absolute;
    right:-4px;
    top:1px;
}

.steps p {
    background: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 14px;
 font-size: 10px;
 width: 10em;
 padding: 0 10px 0 0px;
 text-align: center;
}


.closed .num:after {
 border-left-color:#000
}

.closed .num {
 color:#fff;
 background:#000
}

.closed .num.last:after {
 display:none
}

.open .num:after {
    border-left-color:#ccc;
    border-top-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:transparent;
    z-index:1;
}

.open .num:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    border-top: 15px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
    border-left: 15px solid #7dba00;
    position:absolute;
    right:-5px;
    top:0;
    z-index:0;
}

.open .num {
 background:#ccc;
}

.open .wrap {
 border-radius:15px 0 0 15px;
 border:1px solid #7dba00;
}

li.open:after {
    content:" ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 16px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 16px solid #fff;
    border-left: 15px solid #7dba00;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:0;
}

li.open:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content:" ";
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 14px solid #fff;
    position:absolute;
    right:1px;
    top:1px;
    z-index:1;
}

.expanded {
 display:none;
 <!--bbackground-color: red;-->
 padding-right: 900px;
}

.tab {
 <!--background-color: yellow; -->
 <!--border: 2px solid black; -->
 border-collapse: collapse;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 85%;
 margin-left: 230px;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
 
  
.completed span {
    background-color:NONE;
    color:#95db89;
    border:2px solid #95db89;
}

.todo span {
    background-color:none;
    color:#E1E6EB;
    border:2px solid #E1E6EB;
}
  
.list span {
 color:#58D68D;
 font-weight:500;
 font-size: 12px;
}
    
.breadcrumb-pagination div p {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:0;
    margin:30px auto 25px;
 }
    
.active p {
   border-bottom:2px solid #00abc9;
   padding-bottom:27px;
   margin-bottom:0px !important;
   color: #3c4043;
   font-weight:700;  
}

    
.completed p {
    color:#bsb7c1;
  }
 
.list p {
    color:#3c4043;
 font-weight:700;
  }

.completed span::before { 
  content: '\2713' 
}

.title{
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 365px;
 color: #444;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff; 
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 98%;
} 

th {
 background: linear-gradient(#000000, #4d4d4d);
 border-left: 1px solid #555;
 border-right: 1px solid #777;
 border-top: 1px solid #555;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #999;
 color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000; 
}

th:after {
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,.08));
 content: '';
 display: block;
 height: 15%;
 left: 0;
 margin: 1px 0 0 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 width: 100%;
}

th:first-child {
 border-left: 1px solid #777; 
 box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 #999;
}

th:last-child {
 box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 0 #999;
}

td {
 border-right: 1px solid #fff;
 border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
 padding: 8px ;
 position: relative;
 transition: all 300ms;
}

td:first-child {
 box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 #fff;
} 

td:last-child {
 border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
 box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 #fff;
} 

tr {
 background: url(https://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png); 
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
 background: #f1f1f1 url(https://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png); 
}

tr:last-of-type td {
 box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #fff; 
}

tr:last-of-type td:first-child {
 box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 0 #fff;
} 

tr:last-of-type td:last-child {
 box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 #fff;
}

h1 {
 color: #444;
 text-shadow: 
    1px 0px 1px #ccc, 0px 1px 1px #eee, 
    2px 1px 1px #ccc, 1px 2px 1px #eee,
    3px 2px 1px #ccc, 2px 3px 1px #eee,
    4px 3px 1px #ccc, 3px 4px 1px #eee,
    5px 4px 1px #ccc, 4px 5px 1px #eee,
    6px 5px 1px #ccc, 5px 6px 1px #eee,
    7px 6px 1px #ccc;
 text-align: center;
}

a:hover,a:focus{
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons\">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1> ORDER TRACKING SYSTEM </h1>
<br>
 <table class="multiAccount">
  <tr>
    <th>Account #</th>
    <th>Order #</th>
    <th>Current Status (Ongoing)</th>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow">4579637</span></td>
 <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow">5822412</span></td>
    <td valign="top" class="collapsed"><ol class="steps">
        <li>
                <div class="num green"><b>1</b></div>
        </li>
        <li>
                <div class="num green"><b>2</b></div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num grey"><b>3</b></div>
                        <p><span>Order Provisioning</span><span>Done: 08/25/2014</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>4</b></div>
        </li>
        <li class="closed">
                <div class="num last"><b>5</b></div>
        </li>
</ol></td> 
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow">6784120</span></td>
 <td valign="top"><span class="closedArrow">7893200</span></td>
    <td valign="top" class="collapsed"><ol class="steps">
        <li>
                <div class="num green"><b>1</b></div>
        </li>
        <li>
                <div class="num green"><b>2</b></div>
        </li>
        <li class="closed">
                <div class="num"><b>3</b></div>
        </li>
  <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num grey"><b>4</b></div>
                        <p><span>Service Activation</span><span>Done: 08/25/2014</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="closed">
                <div class="num last"><b>5</b></div>
        </li>
</ol></td> 
   <td colspan="2" class="expanded">
  <ol class="steps">
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num green"><b>1</b></div>
                        <p><span>Order Provisioning</span><span>Done: 08/25/2014</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num green"><b>2</b></div>
                        <p><span>Order Provisioning</span><span>Done: 08/25/2014</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num grey"><b>3</b></div>
                        <p><span>Order Provisioning</span><span>Done: 08/25/2014</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black"><b>4</b></div>
                        <p><span>Order Provisioning</span><span>Done: 08/25/2014</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="open">
                <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="num black last"><b>5</b></div>
                        <p><span>Order Provisioning</span><span>Done: 08/25/2014</span></p>
                </div>
        </li>
</ol>
<div class="tableDiv">
  <div class="tab-content tabs">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Section1">
                        <table border="2px">
       <tr><th>ITEM</th><th>DETAILS</th></tr>
       <tr><td>Order No.</td><td>5822412</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Account Name:</td><td>Mead O'Brien</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Services:</td><td>UNE POTS/T-1</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Installation Address:</td><td>1217 W Capitol Ave,  Little Rock, AR 72201 </td></tr>
       <tr><td>Project Coordinator:</td><td>John Smith</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Phone:</td><td>501-375-3719</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Email:</td><td>jsmith@company.com</td></tr>
       
      </table>
                    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
  </tr>
</table>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way, only clicked row will be affected

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.closedArrow').click(function() {
         $(this).parents('tr').children('.expanded').toggle();
         $(this).parents('tr').children('.collapsed').toggle();
         $(this).toggleClass( "openArrow" );    
    });
});
```